# Decompor o valor de uma cédula em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso ler um valor inteiro e calcular o menor número de notas possíveis (cédulas) no qual o valor pode ser decomposto. As notas consideradas são de 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2 e 1.

E dps imprimir o valor lido e, em seguida, a quantidade mínima de notas de cada tipo necessárias.

**EXEMPLO:**

- entrada

576

- saída

R$ 576

5 nota(s) de R$ 100,00

1 nota(s) de R$ 50,00

1 nota(s) de R$ 20,00

0 nota(s) de R$ 10,00

1 nota(s) de R$ 5,00

0 nota(s) de R$ 2,00

1 nota(s) de R$ 1,00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que isso resolva, como não foi especificado o python eu utilizei python 2.7 mas isso pode ser facilmente convertido para o 3.x

```
N = int(input()) 

notas = [100.00,50.00,20.00,10.00,5.00,2.00,1.00]
print ("R$ %d:"%(N))
for x in notas:
    print ("%i nota(s) de R$ %.2f"%((N/x),x))
    N %= (x)
```

Edit: A multiplicação e por conta da divisão de python que pode arredondar de forma um pouco diferente para floats , arrumei melhor para inteiros

Edit2: Código para python 3.x

Edit3: Tinha esquecido a nota de 1 real

Edit4: Utilizando virgula no lugar de ponto ficaria assim:

```
N = int(input()) 

notas = [100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
print ("R$ %d:"%(N))
for x in notas:
    print ("%i nota(s) de R$ %d,00"%((N/x),x))
    N %= (x)
```